# This period saw them ACCEPT expensive projects and SIGN an agreement

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, verbs-of-perception

> This authoritarian period saw the Maldives **accept** highly expensive infrastructure projects as part of China’s Belt and Road Initiative and even **sign** a free trade agreement with Beijing.

Is the above sentence correct with respect to the words in bold? I think the verb tense used here *accept*, *sign* is incorrect.

Still I am confused about using present continuous or past tense in the above sentence. Please help me with correct construction.

This authoritarian period saw the Maldives (accept/accepted/accepting) highly expensive infrastructure projects as part of China’s Belt and Road Initiative and even (sign/signed/signing) a free trade agreement with Beijing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original sentence is correct - it is using the **bare infinitive** form of the verbs (the infinitive minus the word **to**).  It is also correct to use **accepting/signing**, although the emphasis is slightly different (see below).  It is *not* correct to use **accepted/signed**.

Many verbs of perception [follow this pattern](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing): hear, see, notice, watch, etc., where the following verb takes either the bare infinitive or the -ing form.  When the bare infinitive is used, it emphasizes the *entire completed action*, while using the -ing form emphasizes the *action in progress*.

> I saw him **sit** on the chair.  [bare infinitive: I saw the complete action of him sitting down onto the chair.]
>
> I saw him **sitting** on the chair.  [ -ing form: I saw him while he was continuously seated on the chair.]
>
> *I saw him **sat** on the chair. [*Incorrect* - you cannot use the simple past in this construction.]

In your quoted example, the emphasis is properly on the complete actions of accepting and signing, so the bare infinitive **accept/sign** is used.