# Why not use "opened" instead of "open"?

Tags: grammar

these is a sentence:
"the cat ran into the kitchen when he heard the can open."
I have a question,why not use "opened" instead of "open"?

Comment: This is the same answer as in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/204657/this-period-saw-them-accept-expensive-projects-and-sign-an-agreement/204665#204665).  A verb of perception (like **heard**) should be followed by a bare infinitive (like **open**).

Comment: @CanadianYankee There's nothing wrong with following it with *being opened* or *opening*.

Comment: @CanadianYankee thank u, very useful

Comment: @JasonBassford - You are correct, and use of the -ing form is covered in the link in my previous comment.